# facebook-api - how to retrieve all of a user's friend's events in as few calls and as robust manner as possible?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In terms of getting data from facebook servers, it [sounds like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875885/javascript-should-i-request-one-big-blob-of-data-or-a-series-of-smaller-ajax-r) I should keep the number of calls to the API as small as possible.

What I want to do is compare the logged-in user's events against each of their friend's events. If I try to request all of my events, plus all of my friend's events in one go, I get an unknown error from facebook. Some searching around suggests this is due to the size of the request. Also, when I search for individual friend's events, I can get their events back okay using the same permission token which suggests it's not a permission problem.

Also, I get the error whether I make the call from the Graph API Explorer or from the browser console which suggests it's not js sdk issue.

FWIW, here is the call I was using to get the error

```
211600268?fields=id,events,friends.fields(events)
```

The id used above is my facebook id :)

I have read about using pagination and I think it may help. However, I am not sure how many requests I should break the up into. Should I take the approach of, make as big a call as allowed (i.e. allowed == facebook doesn't throw 'unknown' error) or is there some kind of heuristic/rule of thumb here?

Also, once I understand how many calls the primary request should be broken into, how do I use pagination to say "okay facebook api, please give me the first half of my friend's events" and then "okay facebook api, please give me the other half of my friend's events?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the best answer I have gotten, is my own one. I am not going to include all the details in code here because they are ugly and not important IMO, but here is the gist. It doesn't seem like too many people are interested in the answer to this question so I won't waste my time fleshing it out. But if you want more details I will happily elaborate.

I use FB.login to get the permissions I need.

Success callback to FB.login
FB.api('/me' ...) to get the user's id

Success callback to FB.api('/me' ...)
FB.api call to get user's events and friends list

Success callback to this FB.api call
I use another FB.api call to get a friend's event details (Friend A). I then request another friend's event details (Friend B) as a success callback to the call to get Friend A's details. I then continue this recursively until all the friends events have been covered.

The method leaves a bad taste in my mouth with all the success callbacks changed to each other and it takes ages (about 2 minutes) to do the analysis. But it's all I have got.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i understand, fb permissions have changed recently and all you can get is the list of user's friends that are using your app. (meaning all user's friend's which are not using your app are missing):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog/
was this effecting your code? 
i working on a simmilar project and would love to cooperate or ask for advise.
Please feel free to ping me at any time :)

Comment: I have actually changed my app to rely on facebook's api as little as possible. v1.0 of the api was a major pain in the ass to use and I don't really trust that facebook would change their api to make third party app developers' lives easier.

Comment: But if I can help you out, please let me know :)